# Unable to skip passed test cases and test only failed test case in testNG

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, testng

I'm trying to automate a website testing using testNG.

Let assume I have created 3 test cases one for each webpage(although there are more than 50 test cases in my case but just for simplifying the issue I have considered 3 only).

Now, my starting 2 test cases are passing but my 3rd test case is getting failed. I am making the code change to that 3rd page and I want just to run that 3rd test case but when I am running my code, everytime new IE driver instance is getting created and testing starts from beginning.

How to use existing driver instance and test the 3rd webpage only. I tried googling this out but couldn't find anything useful.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Would you share your test code?

Comment: Hi, Please provide some code how webdriver is initialized and classes are using it etc.. so help you

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ignore particular test, you can use this snippet:

```
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class IgnoreTest {

   @Test(enabled = false) // this test will be ignored
   public void testPrintMessage() {
      System.out.println("This test is ignored");
   }

   @Test
   public void testSalutationMessage() { // this will be executed
      System.out.println("Test works");
   }
}
```

When you execute this class, it will be only second test executed. I don't know if you have stored all 50 tests in one class(hopefully not), but if yes, there is a possibility to group your tests. To be able to do this you can use this sample:

```
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class GroupTestExample {
   @Test(groups = { "functest", "checkintest" })
   public void testPrintMessage() {
      System.out.println("Inside testPrintMessage()");
   }

   @Test(groups = { "checkintest" })
   public void testSalutationMessage() {
      System.out.println("Inside testSalutationMessage()");
   }

   @Test(groups = { "functest" })
   public void testingExitMessage() {
      System.out.println("Inside testExitMessage()");
   }  
}
```

then `xml` file would be like this:

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >

<suite name = "Suite1">
   <test name = "test1">

      <groups>
         <run>
            <include name = "functest" />
         </run>
      </groups>

      <classes>
         <class name = "GroupTestExample" />
      </classes>

   </test>
</suite>
```

then after compiling your test classes, use this command:

```
C:\TestNG_WORKSPACE>java -cp "C:\TestNG_WORKSPACE" org.testng.TestNG testng.xml
```

More explained information you will get in this tutorials:

- [ignore tests](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/testng/testng_ignore_test.htm)
- [group tests](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/testng/testng_group_test.htm)